# What is the best practice of using if condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```js
var foo = "bar";
if (foo) {
  console.log(foo);
}

var foo = "bar";
if (!!foo) {
  console.log(foo);
}
```

Which one should I use?

Performance wise both ways look same.

https://jsperf.com/ifconditioncheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `!!` is not not

Inside the if() both are valid, 2nd one just force it to become a bool value but really not needed. So just go with `if (foo)`

### but if you want to do assign another variable there is a difference. See example below:

```js
var foo = "bar";

var myvar = foo;
var myvar2 = !!foo;

console.log("myvar-->" + myvar);
console.log("myvar2-->" + myvar2);
```

> Read more about JS truthy-falsey: https://j11y.io/javascript/truthy-falsey/

[image: javascript truthy-falsey]

Answer (score 1):

The first. The second one doesn't read well and I can't see an obvious use for it.

Comment: Unless micro-optimizations are a must, readable code is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You add a condition in the second block with !!foo, it would require more time.
Basically, if you run thousands of time with boucle the same if, you will see that the first one has the best performance

example:

```
var foo = "bar"; 
var n = new Date().getMilliseconds();
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    if (foo) {console.log(foo);}
}
var n2 = new Date().getMilliseconds();
var elasped_time = n2-n;
console.log(elasped_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the availability of a value in string foo use

```
var foo = "bar";
if (foo) {

}
```

But this is not the best way to check for a empty string .